# how to convert csv data into list of {key : value} pair?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have csv data in this format :-

```
French, English
partie, part
histoire, history
chercher, search
seulement, only
police, police
pensais, thought
aide, help
demande, request
```

and I want to convert this csv file into list of key : value pairs like this:-

```
[{word: value }, {word2:value2}, {word3:value3}]
```

I want to do this with the help of pandas in python3.
thanks in advance....

I searched everywhere to find the solution for this one but i didn't get the solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It would be better to provide the exact expected output for clarity

Comment: In short, **`kvPairs = [{k:v} for k, v, *_ in pd.read_csv(path_to_csv_file).to_dict('split')['data']]`**; use `pd.read_csv(path_to_csv_file, header=None)...` if your file doesn't have a header row [otherwise the first row will be skipped]. For more details, look into [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), [`.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), and [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension).

Comment: and maybe also look up [`.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) [for iterating through the rows of a DataFrame] and [dictionary comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension) [if you decide on a single dictionary instead of a list of single-key dictionaries]

Answer (score 0):

```
# Load the data into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Convert df to dict with orient="split".
listresult=df.to_dict(orient="split")['data']

# convert to the required format.
dict_list =  [{k: v} for k, v in listresult]
print(dict_list)
# [{'partie': 'part'}, {'histoire': 'history'}, {'chercher': 'search'}, {'seulement': 'only'}, {'police': 'police'}, {'pensais': 'thought'}, {'aide': 'help'}, {'demande': 'request'}]
```

Comment: Because the OP says the data is in CSV format the first line should be `df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', header = 0)`

Answer (score 0):

load the data
df = pd.read_csv("yourfilename")

Use the list comprehension. I am using zip function as well.
mydict = {val1:val2 for val1,val2 in zip(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,1])}

There is a good youtube content from Corey schager about list comprehension: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dt4OGnU5sM

Answer (score 0):

Use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
import pandas as pd

d = (pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=r',\s*', engine='python')
       .set_index('French')['English'].to_dict()
    )

print(d)
```

*NB. if you want the English words are key replace `.set_index('French')['English']` with `.set_index('English')['French']`.*

Alternatively, using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dict):

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=r',\s*', engine='python')

d = dict(zip(df['French'], df['English']))
```

Output:

```
{'partie': 'part', 'histoire': 'history', 'chercher': 'search',
 'seulement': 'only', 'police': 'police', 'pensais': 'thought',
 'aide': 'help', 'demande': 'request'}
```